# Alternative to postThreadMessage/peekmessage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

There's a (static) thread in my C++ application, frequently doing something. To exchange information between the thread and my application I use methods `PostThreadMessage` and `PeekMessage`.

Due to some reason I can't use these methods anymore but don't know a good alternative. Does anybody have an advice? I just want to exchange simple parameters.

Comment: Those methods seem to be either specific of your application or specific of your framework... in either case it is difficult to provide an answer without knowing more about your application. Could you add some [scce](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that both methods are part of the WinAPI. They are good to send and receive information to/in a thread. Very simple. I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Why are you trying to use something else? What is the issue with peek message? Maybe you can alter it to suit your needs.

Comment: Doing it all yourself, you can have a queue with a container of your messages. You need to protect it with a mutex to ensure that you're not modifying  it from two simultaneous threads. And it needs to be contained in somewhere accesible both from the main thread and the worker thread (e.g. a singleton or a reference provided to the thread). That's a simple setup. Going for more complex stuff... you might want to look at the [ACE library](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) ... but that's a whole new world.

Comment: "accesible both from the main thread and the worker thread" -> That is my problem. Because the thread is static (needs to be started with _begintherad()) I can't exchange simple objects with the mainthread. That's why I'm asking here for help. I think a singleton could be a solution, but is there something more easier?

Comment: Consider yourself lucky, you should *never* use PostThreadMessage() to post messages to an app that creates windows.  Use PostMessage() instead, you need to know the window handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't *"exchange simple object with the main thread"* as you said in a comment. A common pattern for sharing an instance of a class between threads is to do something like this:-

Declare your class with a `static` function that can be targeted by `_beginthread` and an instance function that does the work:

```
class CMyClass
{
    // ... other class declarations ...

private:
    static void __cdecl _ThreadInit(void *pParam);    // thread initial function
    void ThreadFunction();                            // thread instance function

    void StartThread();                               // function to spawn a thread

    // ... other class declarations ...
};
```

Define the functions something like this:

```
void CMyClass::StartThread()
{
    // function to spawn a thread (pass a pointer to this instance)
    _beginthread(CMyClass::_ThreadInit, 0, this);
}

void __cdecl CMyClass:_ThreadInit(void *pParam)
{
    // thread initial function - delegate to instance
    CMyClass *pInstance = (CMyClass*)pParam;
    pInstance->ThreadFunction();
}

void CMyClass:ThreadFunction()
{
    // thread instance function is running on another
    // thread but has (hopefully synchronised) access
    // to all of the member variables of the CMyClass
    // that spawned it ....
}
```

Makes sense? The general idea is just to use the `static` function with a passed `this` pointer to connect back to a specific instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was lokking for. :)